# Replace all strings except the parenthesis part in vim

Tags: regex, vim

I have a text as follows.

```
cat
dog
elephant
cat (1)
zebra(1)
snow leopard
shark (other)
animal (hi) (2)
```

and I want to replace them as follows.

```
[[cat]]
[[dog]]
[[elephant]]
[[cat]] (1)
[[zebra]](1)
[[snow leopard]]
[[shark]] (other)
[[animal (hi)]] (2)
```

Any ideas?

Thank you for advance.

*Note* the difference between `cat (1)` and `zebra(1)`(line 4~5), the space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could match as few characters as possible with a non-greedy `.\{-}`, then optionally match a parenthesized group, then match the end of the line:

```
:%s/\(.\{-}\)\( \?([^)]*)\)\?$/[[\1]]\2/
```

Comment: Would you explain what `\@=` means?

Comment: @plhn: It’s a lookahead assertion. The `\($\| (\)` group that precedes it is tested but not matched.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice but I had to modify my question. It had a *bug*.

Comment: @plhn: Updated.

Comment: Ryan, if I want to handle a new type like `animal (hi) (2)`, do you have any idea?

Comment: Actually, I didn’t examined whole dataset... At first, I thought to process whole text data with *big* languages like C++, python, but maybe some clever (and simple) way can be possible, course I didn’t know. So I asked. I’m very sorry if I was teasing you. (And the expected format is `[[animal (hi)]] (2)`)

Comment: @plhn: No, I’m just wondering what exactly the input format is. You want to get everything up until the *last* parenthesized group, optionally with one space?

Comment: @ Ryan Exactly.

Comment: @plhn Updated with a new explanation.

Answer (score 2):

My solution using very magic regex:

```
/\v(^\w+(\s\w+)?)
:%s,,[[\1]],g

First the search
\v ......... stats very magic (avoiding lots of scapes)
( .......... starts group one
^ .......... beginning of line
\w+ ........ at least one word
( .......... starts group two inside group one (it will become optional at the end
\s ........  space
\w+ ........ another word 
) ........... closes groupo two
? ........... makes group two optional inside groupo one
) ........... closes group one
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use the regex:

```
:%s/^.\(.*(\d\)\@!.*\|^.\{-}\(..*(\d\)\@!/[[&]]
```